# styler plugin opengeo suit sdk

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geoserver-rest-api

I try to add the gxp styler plugin, to my suit sdk, but I cannot make it work perfectly.

I had to set up a digest authentication in geoserver (and the user has to log in to see any layer), and I have two users (admin, client). The styler plugin icon is inactive after log in and the browser says:

```
PUT http://91.109.10.190:9080/geoserver/rest/styles 401 (Unauthorized)
```

It will change to active only one case, when I log in to geoserver and to the sdk viewer on the same browser.

Can somebody provide me a solution what sould I change in the code or in geoserver? (probably something in the geoserver)